# Get unevenly seperated fields from bash command

Tags: bash, awk, bzip2

I am  writing a script and wanting to run bzip2 but only get the compression ratio, the compressed size, and uncompressed size.

when i run `bzip2 filename`, I get :

`test.txt:  5.769:1,  1.387 bits/byte, 82.67% saved, 48108 in, 8339 out.`

I only want to get the last three fields:

```
82.67% saved, 48108 in, 8339 out
```

I have tried awk using

`bzip2 -v test.txt | awk '{print $1 $2 $3}'` as well as

`bzip2 -v test.txt | awk -F', ' '{print $1}'`

but since its a string and the delimiters are not evenly spaced, I dont know how to go about it. I would also like to get rid of any text, just outputting the numbers, like this
`82.67% 48108 8339`

I have to keep this as simple as possible. thanks!

**edit:**

output of `bzip2 -v test.txt | cat -A` :

```
test.txt:  0.788:1, 10.154 bits/byte, -26.92% saved, 52 in, 66 out.
```

**script:**

```
#!/bin/sh
# program2.sh 

#Name of the file input
NAME=$1

#Uncompressed size of the file input
UNCOMPRESSED=$(du -h $NAME | awk '{print $1}')



#################################################

#Prompts name entry if no argument provided, or stores given argument as name
if [ $# -eq 0 ];
  then
    echo "Error: No file name provided. Please run the script with a filename argument." 
    echo ""
    exit
fi

echo ""
echo "$NAME will be compressed using the gzip, bzip2, and zip commands."
echo ""
echo "gzip:"

#echoUncompressed:\t $UNCOMPRESSED"
gzip $NAME 
gzip -l  ${NAME%}.gz | awk ' NR == 2 {print "Uncompressed:\t " $2} NR == 2 {print "Compressed:\t " $1}   NR == 2 {print "Ratio:\t\t " $3}'
gunzip ${NAME%}.gz


echo ""
echo "bzip2:"
echo "Uncompressed:\t $UNCOMPRESSED"
#Run bzip2 
bzip2 -v $NAME |& awk -F ',[[:blank:]]*' '{sub(/\.$/, ""); printf "Ratio: %s, Uncompressed: %s, Compressed: %s\n", $(NF-2), $(NF-1), $NF}'
bunzip2 ${NAME%}.bz2


echo ""
echo "zip:"
#echoUncompressed:\t $UNCOMPRESSED"
#Run zip 
zip -q ${NAME%.*}.zip $NAME 
ZNAME="${NAME%.*}.zip"
unzip -ov $ZNAME | awk ' NR == 4 {print "Compressed:\t " $3}   NR == 4 {print "Ratio:\t\t "   $4}'
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
bzip2 -v test.txt |& awk -F ',[[:blank:]]*' '{sub(/\.$/, "");
printf "Ratio: %s, Uncompressed: %s, Compressed: %s\n", $(NF-2), $(NF-1), $NF}'
```

```
Ratio: 82.67% saved, Uncompressed: 48108 in, Compressed: 8339 out
```

Here `-F ',[[:blank:]]*'` makes comma followed by 0 or more whitespace as input field separator for `awk`.

[**Working Script Demo**](https://ideone.com/m7cxmP)

Comment: it still output the full -v command. :( what is OFS and why the tab in the -F argument?

Comment: even after changing to blank it still outputs the full command

Comment: `-v OFS=', '` sets output field separator as literal `', '`. Provide output of `bzip2 -v test.txt | cat -A` in your question

Comment: Check updated answer. It seems `bzip2 -v` writes output on `stderr` instead of `stdout` that is why you need `|&` instead of just `|`

Comment: youre the best thanks!! is there any way i can add text between fields? such as {print $("Ratio:" NF-2), $("Uncompressed" NF-1), $"Compressed" NF} ?

Comment: @anubhava, thanks a TON sir, 1 day I want to become knowledgeable like you, how to become so? :)

Comment: @RavinderSingh13: Thanks for kind words. Your answers are already getting better and many times I have found your approach better than mine.

Comment: @anubhava, you are so kind sir, trust me or not in a day I give 1 hour to read only your answers(as those itself is a Ocean of knowledge), you are always in my prayers as you helping people a lot, GOD bless you sir, you ROCK :)

Comment: im sorry this worked by itself but it didnt work in my script. im trying to put the command in a script and it says `unexpected &`

Comment: @anubhava added the relevant portion

Comment: @anubhava that was a typo when i was putting it here. still doesnt run in the script. i really appreciate this help im sorry for the trouble

Comment: Still it shows `bzip2 -v $NAME |$` instead of `bzip2 -v "$NAME" |&`. Besides this script doesn't show where variable `$NAME` is assigned. You need to post a [short, self-contained, runnable script](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @anubhava i have added the full script

Comment: @anubhava check out my answer

Comment: `however in a script redirection from stderr to stdout is different`: No that is not correct.

Comment: I have added a working script demo in question that uses `|&` in script.

Comment: Ah I know why your script didn't work. You have `#!/bin/sh` at the top which should be `#!/bin/bash`

Answer (score 1):

Following simple `awk` may help you on same:

```
your command |& awk '{sub(/.*byte, +/,"");print}'
```

Edited as per anubhava sir'e suggestion `!&` to answer now too.

```
bzip2 -v Input_file |& awk '{sub(/.*byte, +/,"");split($0,a," ");print "Ratio: ",a[1],",Uncompressed: ",a[2]," Compressed:",a[3]}'
```

Comment: i still got the full output of bzip2 -v

Comment: is there any way i can add text between fields? like in my comment on anubhava answer? yours worked as well though!

Comment: @jrdev, check now.

Comment: im sorry this worked by itself but it didnt work in my script. im trying to put the command in a script and it says unexpected &

Comment: check out my answer

Answer (score 1):

so when not using a script the solutions above work. however in a a script redirection from stderr to stdout is different:

```
bzip2 -v $NAME 2>&1| awk -F ',[[:blank:]]*' '{sub(/\.$/, ""); printf "Ratio: %s, Uncompressed: %s, Compressed: %s\n", $(NF-2), $(NF-1), $NF}'
```

use `2>&1` to redirect in a script , out of the script you can just use `command |& ...."` as in the other solutions

Comment: Please avoid posting a script with a minor insignificant change as a separate answer. This has same awk command as I suggested.